# Alternative ZigBee Stack

Tags: stack, pic, pic18, zigbee

Is there any stack that can be an alternative for the Microchip ZigBee Stack? I have a PIC18F27J53 microcontroller and MRF24J40MB Transceiver. I tried to read and understand the examples included in the Microchip ZigBee Stack but I have no luck. I think the examples are too complex for beginners like me. I only intend to send and receive data to and from sensor nodes. Also, PIC18F27J53 is not included in the Zena Configuration Tool device list.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1.You can try cc2500 rf pro. Its easier, cleaner and quite inexpensive than ZigBee. 

2. OR even better you can try to use ZigBee with the arduino. You have inbuilt libraries, and if you say you are a beginner, then sending data will be as easy as writing to the UART port, which is by the way a one line command. 
3. OR if you dont mind lower frequencies you can go for the standard rf module (or so it is called). You can find more about it, and how to use it here. http://extremeelectronics.co.in/rf/rf-communication-between-microcontrollers-part-i/ 
I would go for Option 2 first, then 3 then 1. (since you said that you are a beginner).

Comment: thank you for your answer and I appreciate it. The problem is that I am restricted in using the PIC18F27J53 and MRF27J53.